# 'sideways' Android app crashing on rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 on Android 6.0.1

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-5, crashes

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 on Android 6.0.1 and am trying to open the [sideways](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bolito2.rallygo) app (package name: `com.bolito2.rallygo`). When opening the app, the message "Unfortunately, sideways has stopped."

I have tried restarting my phone and reinstalling the app, both which do not work. I also tried opening the app before rooting the phone in order to get the log.

Using Matlog, I have recorded the log of the app crashing which is available here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xsT-7wXJfv9jbPtcE7a5JRjye9gV6cnh?usp=sharing

Can anyone please advise why the app is crashing?